# Azure Cosmos DB syntax for REPLACE method

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm working with the Cosmos SDK in my my Node.js app. I've been able to query the database successfully but I'm having trouble with the REPLACE method. I'm wanting to update a single item in the database either by the unique 'id' field or the build in '_rid' field.

Here is the how I currently have it formatted (which returns the error: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system):

```
const { resource: updatedItem } = await client.database(databaseId).container(contianerId).item('2INhAI1fcdkSAAAAERFAAA==', 'TX').replace(newJsonObject);
```

Sample Item:
'state' is the partition key

```
{
    "DateTime": "01-28-19 11:55:48",
    "id": "15",
    "resolved": false,
    "state": "TX",
    "_rid": "2INhAI1fcdkSAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/2INhAA==/colls/2INhAI1fcdk=/docs/2INhAI1fcdkSAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"fd03208d-0000-0700-0000-5fc68a550000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1606847061
}
```

Comment: You should be querying `id`, not `_rid`. What issue are you having, querying by id? Perhaps edit your question to show that query, and what error you receive?

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by simply using the string value for id instead of _rid

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being the correct syntax for what I needed:

```
const { resource: updatedItem } = await client.database(databaseId).container(contianerId).item('15', 'TX').replace(newJsonObject);
```

where the value for the id and the value for the predefined partition key (state in my example) are the properties provided for the item.